# How can I save text on a screen to a string with Xamarin.UI tests?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.uitest

I am testing a page where you see information about yourself, then you can update that information. I cannot find a way to compare a string to text that is displayed on the screen.

For example:

```
Name: John Doe
```

I edit (through another class and method), giving the name "Jane Deer"

```
editName("Jane Deer");
```

Now I want to check that the display on the app updates to "Jane Deer".

How can I read text from a view and make it a string in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query for an element you will get back an array of [AppResult](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppResult). You can get the first element from this array and get the `Text` property from that like so:

```
var name = app.Query(x => x.Id("myElement")).First().Text;
Assert.AreEqual("Jane Deer", name);
```